# ASP.NET MVC2 Route Mapping ignore action and id

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm trying to add a FAQ section to a website that I'm working on and I want to ignore any action or id that is added to the URL.

The RegisterRoutes method of the Global.asax.cs file has been changed to;

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
  routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

  routes.MapRoute(
      "FAQ",
      "FAQ",
      new {controller = "FAQ", action= "Index"});

    routes.MapRoute(
      "Default", // Route name
      "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
      new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } 
    );
}
```

The FAQController.cs looks like this;

```
public class FAQController : Controller
{
    private FAQModel _faq = new FAQModel();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(_faq.GetFAQ());
    }
}
```

But this doesn't appear to be working, I was wondering whether anyone could point me in the right direction of how to do this.

Thanks for any help in advance

Satal :)

Comment: "But this doesn't appear to be working" - how are you testing it, and what results are you seeing?

Comment: I am testing it by pressing "Start Debugging" in the VS 2010 IDE and then trying to navigate to /FAQ/1, when I go there I get the default 404 message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "FAQ", 
    "FAQ/{*pathInfo}", 
    new { controller = "FAQ", action = "Index" }
);
```